# This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components

Tags: .net, oracle11g

I have developed a .Net console application where I am connecting to oracle data base to get some data. It is working fine from DEV machine

I then installed this EXE on a 32 bit server where 32 bit oracle client is installed. When I run this EXE from that server, no issues.

Now, I have created one ASP.Net application where I am running this EXE using `System.Diagnostic.Process` class. Deployed this application on 64 bit windows server where 64bit Oracle client is installed.

When I run this application and went to that page where this EXE is running, I could see below error:-

> ***attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.
>
>   This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed***

Can anyone throw some light on this issue? Thanks

Comment: Was your program compiled using "Any CPU" or some other configuration that's not locked to a specific architecture?

Comment: Thanks for the hint provided. Platform target was set as x86. Now I changed that to AnyCPU. It is working good. Thanks again!!

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32